# How does JWE guarantee authentication?

Tags: jwt, jwe

I know about JWT/JWS where you sign a a token using a private key. You can spread the public publicly on the internet and everyone can verify the token was made by you.

However, with JWE the public key is used to encrypt the token, and the private key is used to decrypt the token. If I publicly spread the public key, everyone can create a token and I am the only one able to decrypt it. SO how is the token authenticated if everyone can make it?

Comment: With JWE you're not supposed to spread any keys (btw, there are two modes of encryption there, usually. A CEK is used with a symmetric algo to encrypt your cleartext payload and CEK itself is encrypted with asymmetric algo). A JWE is an opaque blob of text to clients, only your server should be able to generate and read it.

Comment: This is wrong to say the keys are not supposed to be shared.

Answer (score 0):

The benefits of the cypher operations are of different purpose. The main benefits are as follows:

- The digital signature offers authentication, integrity and non-repudiation
- The data encryption offers confidentiality and integrity.

Only the JWS offers you authentication (you know who the issuer is).
When you receive a JWE, you cannot know who computed it.
However, you can have all benefits at once when using nested tokens i.e. the JWE payload is a JWS.